# HTML cache font file

Tags: html, laravel, caching, fonts, font-face

Edited:
Using laravel framework

How do I cache font file instead of fetching a fresh copy everytime?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using .htaccess you can implement your solution. Here is the code for this.

```
# Fonts
# Add correct content-type for fonts
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot 
AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf
AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
AddType image/svg+xml .svg

# Compress compressible fonts
# only uncomment if you dont have compression turned on already. Otherwise it will cause all other filestypes not to get compressed
# AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf application/x-font-opentype image/svg+xml

ExpiresActive on

# Add a far future Expires header for fonts
ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/font-woff2  "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year"
```

Comment: To my understanding, usually font files are not always get updated right? But in case we need to refresh the cache for font files, can I use e.g. myfontfile.ttf?v=1.1 versioning to refresh the cache if I implement your .htaccess solution?

Comment: sorry i added laravel framework if that affects any possible solutions